# Nginx proxy weebly site show weebly 404 error

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm pretty new to Nginx and I'm currently trying to proxy a weebly website (https://ldmryeah.weebly.com/) over Nginx which act as a reverse proxy. However after several attempt all I've got is the default Weebly's 404 page.

Below are some of the configurations that I tried:

```
# most basic one
location /weebly {
      proxy_pass $WEEBLY_ENDPOINT; 
}
```

Also trying that one

```
# tried to emulate how a browser would access to the weebly website
location /weebly {
      proxy_pass $WEEBLY_ENDPOINT;
      proxy_redirect off;
      add_header Host ldmryeah.weebly.com;

      proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "gzip, deflate, br";
      proxy_set_header Accept "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9";
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          \$remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    \$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  \$scheme;
}
```

Furthermore, I also tried to change the trailing edges of the proxy_pass as well as the location without this having an impact on the result.

Does anyone have an idea ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several trials I successfully made it work by using this configuration

```
####
# Weebly
####
location /blog/ {
  proxy_pass https://<website>.weebly.com/;
  proxy_set_header Host <website>.weebly.com;
}

###
# assets
###
location ~ ^/(gdpr|uploads|files|ajax)/ {
  proxy_pass https://<website>.weebly.com;
}
```

Note that the rooting system is not working though you can access it by typing the page directly under the /blog/